# Is my understanding of Access Points and 802.1x profiles correct?

Tags: mac, network, wifi, keychain, 802.1x

I'm trying to logic what the role of 802.1x profiles are. Does the below make sense?

802.11 is a standard for wireless networks with various physical layers and the standard for campus wifi. When an AP sends a connection response to a device, it also sends an authentication framework or profile that the device can use to continue authenticating so that it can connect. We can refer to this framework as a 802.1x profile. 802.1X runs over 802.11 which authenticates mobile stations to the access point by checking the user's identity. The user's identity is determined based on their credentials. When you set up a network, it stores or caches a configuration profile on your device that authenticates via a central authority. You can see the configuration profiles (Wi-Fi or otherwise) that your laptop uses in Settings/System Preferences. Now, when you connect, your device is communicating the profile info to the AP and the AP can confirm it.

So when authentication goes wrong with the user's credentials, it might be that the access point and the device have two different versions of the profile and the device one is outdated or incorrect. So a common troubleshooting technique is to delete and essentially force refresh the profiles, making your device to redo the configuration. It may also help to delete stored information about your credentials (in Keychain access) for similar reasoning!

Answer (score 2):

[802.11X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) is a standard for extendible authentication over [802.11 (aka Wi-Fi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11). This can be in many forms, for example, it may use a username and password, or something more complex like issuing certificates to each device.

Because 802.11X encapsulates things like certificate-based authentication, which cannot be manually entered, macOS allows you to install configuration profiles which pre-configure how the computer will authenticate with the network. However, this is not required to use 802.11X: if it is username/password based, you can manually type them in if desired.